# Unable to update DoubleConversion to it's latest update (1.1.6) in cocoapods

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-fbsdk

I am building a `react-native` app and I want to integrate `react-native-fbsdk`, after building it in Xcode I got the error `library not found for -lDoubleConversion`. So after researching and trying I assumed it's an version issue. How can I update DoubleConversion.

Tried till now:

- Removed node_modules
- Removed Package-lock.json
- npm install
- cd ios
- Removed Podfile.lock (Even did pod deintegrate)
- pod install
- pod update

  - Message after pod install / pod update / pod update DoubleConversion / pod update DoubleConversion -repo-update 
    `**'Pod installation complete! There are 29 dependencies from the Podfile and 30 total pods installed.**'`
- pod try Doubleconversion / pod outdated

  - Gives me the error - `[!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/1/5/8/DoubleConversion/1.1.5/DoubleConversion.podspec.json
    Response: Timeout was reached`
- sudo gem uninstall cocoapods and installed it again
- Moreover at first I thought I might be doing something wrong so I started it from the very beginning from installing `react-native-cli`globally but came and stuck in the same issue again.

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'xyz' do
  # Pods for xyz
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'

  target 'xyzTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'xyz-tvOS' do
  # Pods for xyz-tvOS

  target 'xyz-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

The version in **Podfile.lock** for DoubleConversion `- DoubleConversion (1.1.6)`

So after all the research and the errors I assumed that it's an issue related to version of DoubleConversion as after `pod update` the error shows it's trying to reach version `1.1.5` but as per `Podfile.lock` it wants version `1.1.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I solved it. Instead opening `xcodeproj` open it with `xworkspace`.

Comment: Hi, How did you solved?

Comment: @Paresh.P Open your project with xworkspace.

Comment: I am not able to run my project with double conversion in the device. It gives me errors in the DoubleConversion pod. I can run the project in a simulator though.